# Amazon S3 CORS - enable just for mobile app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-s3

I have a messaging mobile app where you can share images and text.

I got a Amazon S3 bucket where I save all the photos from the app and then I save the path in the database.

What I want to achieve is that the files from my Amazon S3 to be available just on my mobile app. (CORS just for the mobile app)

Is this possible?
Is there a better way to protect the files on Amazon S3 and to be available only in the mobile app?

Can someone explain me a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

CORS is not really a mechanism for securing content.  It is a mechanism for securing browsers, *preventing them from asking for* things they shouldn't be asking for.  The fact that it also restricts some access to content is a side effect.

The simple solution is for your app to sign its requests to S3 -- using signed URLs or sending  `Authorization` header with requests.  You can generate this on your application server, if you have one, or Lambda and API Gateway, and provide the signed links to the app as needed, or you can use cognito and S3 components of the AWS SDK to obtain temporary credentials and generate the  signed links inside the app.

Comment: I was thinking to make a route in my API where I request files from S3 and inside S3 to enable CORS for my API-url, what do you think?

Comment: @Hiero, still if you access the S3 URL directly in new tab of browser, it'll not block the request.
What you need is [Share S3 Objects with Signed-URLS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)